# Forward searching with latex-suite

Tags: linux, vim, dvi, vim-latex

I am using the windows subsystem for Linux and recently installed vim latex (latex-suite). I was following the tutorial and typed

```
:let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

and

```
:TCTarget dvi
```

in gvims command line. However when I type `\ll` and `\ls` nothing happens. It just says `:call Tex_ForwardSearchLaTeX()`. I am using xdvik as my viewer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also - I tried the same thing in an Ubuntu virtual machine and I get the same problem. I thought it might be the viewer but the official website says that xdvik supports forward searching.

Answer (score 1):

After looking around at the `xdvi` documentation (I wasn't using `xdvik` apparently) I found this command for forward searching:

```
:execute "!xdvi -sourceposition " .line(".").expand("%")." ".expand("%:r").".dvi"
```

which works after pressing `/ll`. Is there anyway I can map this to `/ls`? (By going into `latex-suites` config file or something).

Answer (score 0):

I mapped this command by adding the line

```
<f4> :execute "!xdvi -sourceposition " .line(".").expand("%")." ".expand("%:r").".dvi"
```

in

```
~/.vim/after/plugin/maps.vim
```

You can create such a file, vim will find it. In the tex file, add `\uspackage{srcltx}`. Install the package `srcltx.sty` if it is not installed